# MultiUpload Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Tengo un proyecto Django en el cual desde el admin puedo subir fotos de una en una, ahora bien, quiero poder subir más de una para un mismo elemento (registro de la base de datos) y me gustaría saber cual es la manera menos traumatica y fácil, ya que normalmente es solo añadir `enctype="multipart/form-data"` pero en Django todo es muy rebuscado.

He encontrado `django-admin-multiupload` pero me parece algo complejo para lo simple que necesito, no es un formulario externo sino hacer que el simple campo `ImageField` permita múltiples ficheros, tiene que hacer alguna forma de configurar eso, no?

https://github.com/gkuhn1/django-admin-multiupload

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    pho_code = models.AutoField(db_column='PHO_code', primary_key=True) 
    pho_url = models.ImageField(db_column='PHO_url', upload_to='media/documents/%Y/%m/%d') 
    poi = models.ForeignKey(Poi, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='POI_code')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PHOTO'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.pho_url)
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['pho_code', 'pho_url', 'poi']
    form = PhotoForm

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos. Edita tu pregunta siguiendo estas directrices: [http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Con tu modelo actual **no puedes** hacer lo que pretendes. Sin embargo tienes dos opciones:

1. **Usar un campo `JSON`** - Los campos tipo `JSON` tienen un formato *libre*, por lo tanto podrías usarlo para construir un diccionario con *n* número de imágenes. Para el uso de `JSONField` tienes varias opciones y paquetes que puedes encontrar en Internet. Una de estas opciones las ofrece el propio proyecto de Django: [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).
2. **Usar un campo ArrayField** - Al igual que el anterior, permite gestionar colecciones de campos. A diferencia de la opción anterior, todos los campos __deben__ser del mismo tipo, por ejemplo el campo `ImageField`. Igual que el anterior, el campo [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) solo funciona en PostgreSQL.
3. **Usar una tabla relacionada** - Es decir, haces una tabla de imágenes que relaciona cada imagen con tu modelo `Photo` usando claves foráneas, `ForeignKey`. Puedes ver ejemplos de uso en la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships).